# How can I parse aspx and ascx file with Roslyn

Tags: asp.net, webforms, roslyn

I want to refactor a web form application with Roslyn. There are plenty of resource on how to do with source code. I have hard time to find any resource with refactoring aspx and ascx file. Is it even possible? Thanks

Comment: Roslyn has no support for that.